# How to differentiate zsh vs ssh terminals in iterm?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I find it very annoying that the robbyrussell theme does not let me differentiate between zsh and ssh terminals how do I fix that?

Comment: Consider [unix.se] for questions about system configuration (including configuration of your shell or terminal) rather than about software development.

Comment: BTW, when re-asking the question there (or somewhere else where it's topical),  you might want to be more clear about what you're asking -- the distinction between a "zsh terminal" and a "ssh terminal" isn't exactly obvious. (If you have a terminal displaying the output from an instance of zsh, which started a ssh session, which started another, remote zsh instance... which "kind" of terminal is that?)